# JAXB generate schema working in JUNO but not Kepler

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I'm trying to generate schema from JAXB classes using the new project option. 
It is working fine in JUNO but when I try the same in Kepler it gives me the error
I'm not able to figure out why is Kepler throwing this error: 
!loading...!

!
    Not found: cs.clinic.service.dto.PatientDTO!

!
generating schema...!

Please let me know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, had to do Project -> Clean.